# SVN ignore problem

Tags: svn, properties, ignore

How is this possible?

```
> svn status
?       cp/app/cache
?       cp/app/logs

> svn propget svn:ignore
cp/app/cache
cp/app/logs
order/app/cache
order/app/logs
```

It should ignore this 2 directories, but it shows them as unversioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't set `svn:ignore` to file names located in subdirectories. What `svn:ignore` is saying is to ignore a file named "cp/app/cache`that sits in the current directory. Not a file named`cache`that sits in a directory`app`which sites in a directory`cp`. It literally means a file with two forward slashes in its name. Yes, this is illegal under Windows and Unix, but some operating systems do allow files with forward slashes in their names.

If you really want to ignore those files, you need to set `svn:ignore` to `cache` and `log` on the directories `cp/app` and `order/app`

Comment: Wow, thanks. They done it so wrong, I think git solves this in more natural way. Thanks agaion.

Comment: How is this "more natural" in Git? In Git, you can create a global ignore which you can also do in Subversion by editing the `$HOME/.subversion/config` file. You can also put in each directory a `.gitignore` file, but that also doesn't work with files in subdirectories. This is similar to the svn:ignore property in that respect.